# How to Check the total WebPage when it loads including images, JS files CSS files and all other source files it loads. in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is What i Tried. But it is Not Giving total Size.

```
public void getsize()
        {

            String URL = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask";
            try
            {
                System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(URL);
                req.Method = "HEAD";
                using (System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse())
                {
                    double ContentLength;
                    if (double.TryParse(resp.Headers.Get("Content-Length"), out ContentLength))
                    {
                        WebClient client = new WebClient();
                        double kb = ContentLength / 1024;
                        double mb = Math.Round((kb / 1024), 3);

                        Console.WriteLine("The Page size is: " + ContentLength + " Bites or " + kb + " kb or " +  mb + " mb");

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid URL");
                    }

                }
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Something Went Wrong");
            }
```

Suggest any Solution For this Problem Or Give Code if possible That Would be Great.

Comment: I am getting the output for your code "The Page size is: 40275 Bites or 39.3310546875 kb or 0.038 mb"

Comment: Yes it gives output. but i need different output. i need the size of whole page and its contents like images, its stylesheets, js files etc.